# Call prototype without instance

Tags: javascript

I have a class with a method

```js
function MyClass(name){
  this._name = name;
}
MyClass.prototype.test=function(){
  console.log(this._name);
}
```

This work if create new instance

```js
var a = new MyClass('demo');
a.test();
```

But, now I want call this class like a function without create instance

```js
MyClass('demo2').test();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible, constructors are functions. But the behaviour of a constructor called as a function is different to calling it as a constructor.

Comment: If you want to call it as `MyClass('demo2').test()`, then there *needs* to be an instance to call `test` *on*. If you simply don't want to assign the instance to a variable… well, `new MyClass('demo2').test()` works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if `this` is an instance of the class, if the check is false it means that it is called as a function and you can return a new instance:

```
function MyClass(name){
  if (!(this instanceof MyClass)) {
    return new MyClass(name);
  }
  this._name = name;
}
```

in this way you can get a new instance of the class with or without the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can return a custom object with necessary properties.

```js
function MyClass(name){
  // private variable
  var _name = name;
  var getName = function(){
    return _name;
  };
  
  // public properties
  return {
    test: getName
  }
}
console.log(MyClass('Foo').test())
console.log(MyClass('Foo')._name)
```

or you can have inner private class which is only available inside `MyClass`.

```js
function MyClass(name){
  function Person(){
    this._name = name;
  }
  Person.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this._name
  }
  return new Person()
}
console.log(MyClass('Foo').getName())
console.log(MyClass('Foo')._name)
```